# Why use using-statements when you want to reopen connections?

Tags: c#, database, sql, sql-server, winforms

In a Winforms project I've been working on recently, I've been dutifully using using-statements for objects that implement IDisposable. I want to reopen a database connection, however because the using-statement that it was in earlier disposed the connection, I can't reopen it.

So this leads me to the question, is it bad to only be using 1 connection for a small personal program that accesses 1 database (and 2 tables). At this point I am thinking of converting all those using statements into open() and close() statements.

But that's not it. I still have to call dispose() before the program is closed. Is there a way for this to be called when the user exits out?

Comment: Your choices are: 1.  Broaden your `using` statement to encompass more code, so that you don't have to reopen the connection, 2.  Create a new database connection and open that one instead of trying to reopen the original one, 3.  Use `Close()` and `Dispose()` manually.  Which one to use depends on your software's specific requirements.  #3 is the least desirable, because the `using` statement incorporates some `try` `finally` blocks that are sort of important, unless you re-create those.

Comment: The point of using `using` is so that you don't forget to close, even if an exception is thrown. You shouldn't have to "dutifully' do this over and over.  Drop it in a method and use the method over and over. Reopening is meaningless.  It's opened or it's closed.  There is no reopened state.  If you need to communicate often enough that opening and closing is causing to much overhead (be sure of this) then just leave the connection open. Each time you communicate refresh a timeout to close. This works a bit like caching. Setting this timeout to 0 should give you the same behavior you have now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What you guys say makes very good sense. I'm still scratching my head though. I don't want to post code, but say you have a listview that is populated through a SqlConnection on initialization. Once this form is populate the connection is disposed because we won't need to populate the list again. However, due to other actions, we need to open a new connection to the same database. I use a new connection in a using statement. However, I'm getting an exception saying I cannot use a connection that has been closed. I'm using a new connection though, right?

Comment: Post your code on Stack Overflow, and get some advice from the folks there.

Comment: Understand that you can have multiple connections to the same database from the same application.  You're responsible for closing every connection you open.  Between open and close you may use as often as you like.  Once it's closed you don't use it again (or you'll get that exception).  You don't reopen it. You open a new connection to the same database and use that.  Just don't forget to close it.  There is a limit on how many connections the database will allow you to have open at the same time.  There isn't one on how many connections you have closed.  That's why it's important to close.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are using `using` wrongly. The scope of the variable should be limited to the `using` statement. ie, your code should look something like `using var conn = new Connection() { use conn here }`. `conn` in this instance should never be declared outside of the `using` statement.

Comment: Voting to close as this is a request for help with debugging code, without even supplying the code. This belongs on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

.net already uses connection pooling, so when you create/dispose a connection, you are not actually opening and closing a database connection, just fetching and returning a connection to the pool. So you don't really get any benefit by changing to Open/Close, and the using construct guarantees that the connection is returned to the pool correctly even in case of an error.

So you don't need to "re-open" a connection. You just create a new connection.

Answer (score -2):

> is it bad to only be using 1 connection for a small personal program
>   that accesses 1 database (and 2 tables)

You should not limit program to 1 connection. Sooner you will end up situations you require more than one simultaneous connections,

Built in [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx), is reusing connections and will only return connections to pool when you close it (As long as you use the same connection string).

So when you need a connection simply open and once finished dispose of it with `using` statement.

Comment: .net already uses connection pooling.